# Как показать нужный option в зависимости от выбора?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два одинаковых select

```
<label>Заголовок:</label>
<select class="form-control">
 <option value="firfac">1</option>
 <option value="frecsfac">2</option>
</select>

<label>Заголовок2:</label>
<select class="form-control">
 <option>Test1</option>
 <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```

Можно ли как то в зависимости от выбра опции в первом `select` во втором показать опции зависимые от выбора первого.

Например в первом `select` если выбрать первый вариант, то опции у второго будут: `Один, два, три, четыре`. А если выбрать второй, то в опциях будет: `пять, шесть, семь, восемь.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
$('#select1').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Заголовок:</label>
<select name="select1" id="select1" class="form-control">
  <option value="firfac">1</option>
  <option value="frecsfac">2</option>
</select>
<label>Заголовок2:</label>
<select name="select2" id="select2" class="form-control">
  <option value="firfac">1</option>
  <option value="firfac">2</option>
  <option value="firfac">3</option>
  <option value="firfac">4</option>
  <option value="frecsfac">6</option>
  <option value="frecsfac">7</option>
  <option value="frecsfac">8</option>
  <option value="frecsfac">9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: используется JQuery