# Как получить значение option?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html-select

я давно задавал тут [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-option-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). Ответ меня устроил, но сейчас я столкнулся с проблемой.

```
 <label>Выполняемое действие</label>
 <select name="select1" id="select1" class="form-control">
      <option value="user">Подписаться</option>
      <option value="media">Поставить лайк</option>
 </select>
 <label>Выберите файл</label>
 <select name="select2" id="select2" class="form-control">
      <?php  
      $users = DB::table('search')->where('user_id','=' ,$user_id)->get();
      foreach ($users as $item) {
           switch ($item->method) {
                case 'follow':
                     echo "<option value='user'>".$item->name."</option>";
                break;
                case 'like':
                     echo "<option value='media'>".$item->name."</option>";
                break;
                default:
                break;
           }
      }
      ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              $("#select1").change(function() {
              if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
              }
              var id = $(this).val();
              var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
              $('#select2').html(options);
              });
            </script>
```

Но теперь вопрос таков. Как получить значение из `select2`, если там `value` `user` и `media`? В jq, к сожалению, не силён, я как понял, что нужно изменять именно код jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> вот такой рабочий пример сойдёт?

```
<select id="category" onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="">Выберите поиск</option>
    <option value="http://yandex.ru">Яндекс</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">Гугл</option>
</select>

document.getElementById("category").selectedIndex = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < selectTags.length; i++) {
  selectTags[i].selectedIndex =0;
}
```

Comment: Только ниже select,  код должен заключен в <script type="text/javascript">Сюда</script>

Comment: да, да, да гениально, спасибо